# Rolling forecast with DCC-GARCH in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, garch

I have fitted a DCC-GARCH model to my multivariate financial data and do the forecasting. Now, I would like to automate the procedure for a data set that I have.

```
# load libraries
library(rugarch)
library(rmgarch)
library(FinTS)
library(tseries)
Dat = dji30retw[, 1:8, drop = FALSE]

uspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = "sGARCH"), distribution.model = "norm")
spec1 = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(8, uspec)), dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvnorm")
fit1 = dccfit(spec1, data = Dat, out.sample = 141, fit.control = list(eval.se=T))
print(fit1)

#Forecast
dcc.focast=dccforecast(fit1, n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 0)
```

I have 1141 observations with 8 assets. I want to fit a multivariate DCC-GARCH model to the first 1000 data points and use the remaining 114 data points as the out of sample forecasting period. For example :-

```
1) Data[1:1000,] In-sample data, forecast for Data[1001,]
2) Data[1:1001,] In-sample data, forecast for Data[1002,]
3) Data[1:1002,] In-sample data, forecast for Data[1003,]
.. 
4) Data[1:1113,] In-sample data, forecast for Data[1141,]
```

How do I automate the process? I have never done looping before but I have tried to do the following.

Please find the example below:-

```
for (i in 1:2)
{Dat.Initial = dji30retw[, 1:8, drop = FALSE]

 Dat <- Dat.Initial[1:(1000+(i-1)), ] 

  #Fitting the data

  fit1 <- list()
  spec1 <-list()
  uspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = "sGARCH"), distribution.model = "norm")
  spec1[[i]] = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(8, uspec)), dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvnorm")
  fit1[[i]] = dccfit(spec1[[i]], data = Dat, out.sample = 114, fit.control = list(eval.se=T))
  print(summary(fit1[[i]])) }

#Out of sample forecasting
dcc.focast <- list()
dcc.focast[[i]]=dccforecast(fit1, n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 0)
print(dcc.focast[[i]]) 
}
```

However, when I run the code, it comes out like this:

```
  Length  Class   Mode 
   1 DCCfit     S4
```

So where are my results?

**Update:** I have obtained the result for the above question by executing the following command.

```
 for (i in 1:2)
 {Dat.Initial = dji30retw[, 1:8, drop = FALSE]
 Dat <- Dat.Initial[1:(1000+(i-1)), ] 

 fit1 <- list()
 uspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = "sGARCH"), distribution.model = "norm")
 spec1 = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(8, uspec)), dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvnorm")
 fit1[[i]] = dccfit(spec1, data = Dat, out.sample = 114, fit.control = list(eval.se=T))
 print(summary(fit1[[i]])) 
 #Out of sample forecasting
dcc.focast <- list()
dcc.focast[[i]]=dccforecast(fit1[[i]], n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 0)
print(dcc.focast[[i]])
}
```

Suppose that I don't want to over-write the fitted model and forecasting objects, though. From the forecasting, I will get the mean return and the variance-covariance matrix. If the for loop is working, I should get 114 values of mean returns and 114 set of variance covariance matrix.

```
covmat.focast= rcov(dcc.focast)  ##-->Only one covariance matrix.
mean.focast = fitted(dcc.focast)  ##Mean forecast matrix
```

Now, I want to get the mean returns forecast.

```
for (i in 1:2)
{mean.focast <- list()
mean.focast[[i]] = fitted(dcc.focast[[i]]) 
print(mean.focast[[i]]) 
}

#Error in fitted(dcc.focast[[i]]) : error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'fitted': Error in dcc.focast[[i]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

I have not manage to get the variance covariance matrix from the forecast. I have tried to use the following command:-

```
for (i in 1:2)
{
covmat.focast <- list()
covmat.focast[[i]]= dcc.focast@mforecast[i]
print(covmat.focast[[i]]) }
#Error: trying to get slot "mforecast" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots
```

Anyone can help me pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may lie in this line:

```
dcc.focast[[i]]=dccforecast(fit1, n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 0)
```

Here you supply `fit1` which is a list to the `dccforecast` function that requires supplying an object of class `DCCfit` instead.

What you could do to remedy that is run a loop over `i` where in each iteration you would execute the following

```
dcc.focast[[i]]=dccforecast(fit1[[i]], n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 0)
```

Alternatively you may consider using the `dccroll` function which does the rolling for you.

Also note that if `dcc.focast` is a list, you will not be able to execute the following:

```
covmat.focast= rcov(dcc.focast)  ##-->Only one covariance matrix.
mean.focast = fitted(dcc.focast)  ##Mean forecast matrix
```

You should do it element-by-element in a loop over `i`:

```
covmat.focast[[i]]= rcov(dcc.focast[[i]])
mean.focast[[i]] = fitted(dcc.focast[[i]])
```

Comment: Thanks. I can now get the result for the dcc.focast[[i]]. However, I still have problem with covmat.focast[[i]]= rcov(dcc.focast[[i]]). There is error when I execute the comand as you suggested. It says "Error in UseMethod("rcov") : no applicable method for 'rcov' applied to an object of class "NULL". Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: To execute the command rcov, the class for dccforecast, should be in [1] "standardGeneric"attr(,"package") [1] "methods". Is there any other ways to get the covariance matrix from the forecast command? Or any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I have also tried to use the command 

for (i in 1:2)
{ covmat.focast[[i]]= dcc.focast@mforecast[[i]]
    print(covmat.focast[[i]]) }

But there is error saying that "Error: trying to get slot "mforecast" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots"

Comment: There is a method `rcov` for the class `DCCforecast`, so in principle it should work. Make sure that the object you are supplying to `rcov` really is a forecast from a DCC model of a class `DCCforecast`; is it? The error message you cited above seems to indicate otherwise. Another way to extract elements from a `DCCforecast` object is use `slotNames(your_object)` and extract the relevant slots by `your_object@slot_name`. These may be object of class S3 or S4, I don't remember, so you can possible extract deeper elements by using another `@` or `$` at the end: (to be continued)

Comment: I have tried to do like this -->
for (i in 1:2){
    dcc.focast[[i]]=dccforecast(fit1[[i]], n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 0)
    print(dcc.focast[[i]]) }
The first error says that, Error in UseMethod("dccforecast") : 
  no applicable method for 'dccforecast' applied to an object of class "NULL" .

Comment: `your_object@slot_name@slot_name` or `your_object@slot_name$item_name`.

Comment: OK, then you are not getting a proper DCC forecast. For starters I suggest you forget lists and just do one simple example. Then, when your simple example works, put it as the first item of a list. And then proceed to build the remaining items of the list using a loop. That way you will ensure that each step works and will be able to track where the error happens. Meanwhile, if you do a lot of things at once, it is difficult to find the error.

Comment: Okay. First let me edit the reproducible code above to a simple example, so maybe you can suggest me where is the mistakes coming from. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my question. Appreciate if you can help me pls......

Comment: No problem! I would gladly help more if I did not have a full time job!

Comment: Sorry. I might need to ask you again. I have managed to get the list for the dcc.focast, mean.focast and covmat.focast using the codes. But if let say, I type only dcc.focast[i] , it will only come out the value of the last dcc.focast and not all three values which it suppose to display. For example, if I write dcc.focast[[1]], it will gives me "NULL". Why is this happening?

Comment: What kind of beast is `mean.focast[i]`? Perhaps it is a matrix (isn't it?), then you should use double indexation. Or if it is a list, you should use double squared brackets, but you already said this does not work.

Comment: Sorry. In my earlier code in the question, I have put mean.focast =list(). Same with dcc.focast and covmat.focast. if I execute dcc.focast[[1]], it will gives me "NULL". Same goes as dcc.focast[[2]. It will only give me the answer for the last part which is dcc.focast[[3]]. Why? I am so confused now.

Comment: Apparently, when filling in the list some elements did not get filled correctly. There may be a number of mistakes that might have caused that: a small misprint in loop indexation; some models cannot be estimated (do not converge or similar) and the items are not filled; something else. You should inspect the elements one by one to see at which stage they no longer have the values you expect them to have. I encourage you to be patient and do it all step by step. Debugging requires great patience and not always much technical knowledge.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I will try to do it step by step. Thanks anyway!